# PyCharm + IdeaVim: search automatically move moves splitted window to the left

Tags: pycharm, ideavim

PyCharm (Community Edition 3.4.1)

IdeaVim (Build 0.35-234).

My problem is if I vertically split the window and do the vim style search (with '/'), after I hit enter, the tab searched in will be automatically opened in the left window if originally not opened in the left, or input focus will be moved to left if the file is originally opened.

What should I do to eliminate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [VIM-210](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-210). This issue is fixed in the master branch, but it hasn't been released yet. You are welcome to test nightly builds you can get from https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim via the build badge at the top of the README.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. Unfortunately I've switched to pure vim now, and am not able to test it as a result. I'll accept your answer anyway.